# Can Search Engines index individual pages in a JavaScript powered web application?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, web-applications, seo

The web app I'm building has a JavaScript powered interface and fetches data from the server using AJAX. Everyone is on the same "page" but the data after the hashtag in the URL is used to determine which data to load, which is then displayed on the page. An example of a URL in my web app might be http://www.myapp.com/#/user/stackmaster. JavaScript sees the data after the hashtag (in this case "user" and "stackmaster") and uses AJAX to load the user whose username is stackmaster, and then displays it on the screen. The reason I structure my URLs like this because I want search engines to be able to index individual pages.

Is it possible to have an AJAX based web application like this be able to find and index individual pages? It is my understanding that web crawlers such as Google can't index dynamic content loaded with AJAX, right? Are there any alternate techniques to help the search engines find this data?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The latest version of Google's crawler actually does support AJAX, though I'm not sure to what extent. Take a look at their webmaster documentation, specifically these two pages: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot

Comment: This site is for programming related questions, not SEO questions. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is pretty clear about the questions that are proper to ask here, and SEO isn't among them. Voting to close as off topic. (And before you mention it: Older questions may have been asked about SEO, but that was before the creation of StackExchange and sites like [WebMasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you're running an AJAX application with content that you'd like to
>   appear in search results, Google has a new process that, when
>   implemented, can help Google (and potentially other search engines)
>   crawl and index your content. Historically, AJAX applications have
>   been difficult for search engines to process because AJAX content is
>   produced dynamically by the browser and thus not visible to crawlers.
>   While there are existing methods for dealing with this problem, they
>   involve regular manual maintenance to keep the content up-to-date.

[GETTING STARTED](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

An agreement between crawler and server

In order to make your AJAX application crawlable, your site needs to abide by a new agreement. This agreement rests on the following:

> The site adopts the AJAX crawling scheme. For each URL that has
>   dymanically produced content, your server provides an HTML snapshot,
>   which is the content a user (with a browser) sees. Often, such URLs
>   will be AJAX URLs, that is, URLs containing a hash fragment, for
>   example www.example.com/index.html#key=value, where #key=value is the
>   hash fragment. An HTML snapshot is all the content that appears on the
>   page after the JavaScript has been executed. The search engine indexes
>   the HTML snapshot and serves your original AJAX URLs in search
>   results.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html

Comment: Thanks for the great response. This method uses the hashbang (#!) which is a feature Google came up with to help developers like me. Although this is an adequate solution I would prefer not to use it if possible (though I will if I have to), since it is basically a hack, and it is pretty much reviled by respected developers. Twitter engineer Dan Webb wrote a post urging developers not to use them. Twitter used to use #! but stopped in May 2012. I wonder if they just use straight HTTP requests now for content they want indexable. Hm...